# Lucene: converting boolean queries with ORs to ANDs only

Tags: java, solr, lucene, logic, boolean-logic

I need to convert a boolean query with ANDs, ORs and NOTs to ANDs and NOTs only. All my ORs need to be converted to ANDs, obviously maintaining the original meaning.

For example:

```
a AND b AND (c OR d OR e)
```

Should be converted to several separated queries:

```
a AND b AND c
a AND b AND d
a AND b AND e
```

Which is has the same logic result, but it isn't using ORs.
I've tried a lot of different approaches but no real solution yet.
I know I could use some De Morgan's laws maybe, but haven't found a solution yet.

It's important to notice that I need to convert ANY kind of query, not only the one on my example. I have to really cover it all.
As other examples (comma meaning another query):

```
a OR b > a, b
a AND (b OR c) > a AND b, a AND c
a OR (b AND (c OR d)) > a, b AND c, b AND d
...
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
more clear examples:

```
lucene AND (solr OR hadoop) > lucene AND solr, lucene AND hadoop
stackoverflow AND (java OR lucene) -solr > stackoverflow AND java -solr, stackoverflow AND lucene -solr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to convert the search expression to [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form). Then each term of the disjunction can be used as a separate search and the search results combined.

Try googling "convert to disjunctive normal form" for processes and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you encounter an

```
E = a OR b
```

then you can convert OR operation to an AND of NOTs

```
E = NOT NOT E 
E = NOT NOT (a OR b)
E = NOT (NOT a AND NOT b)
```

So you're example would be converted as below:

```
E = a AND b AND (c OR d OR e) 
E = a AND b AND NOT NOT (c OR d OR e) 
E = a AND b AND NOT (NOT c AND NOT d AND NOT e)
```

Comment: In a boolean logic sense, it would work, but in my actual use which is boolean search, it wouldn't. I need to make a search for a AND (b OR c) on Facebook, for example, and it will only accept ANDs, so "NOT a" isn't a search query. In a real world example, the query "lucene AND (solr OR hadoop)", I couldn't search for "-lucene" and so on, got it?

Comment: oh i see, I gotcha